How to detect when Qt program resumes running after Windows is put to sleep and wakes up?
Hi I'm trying to figure out how to detect when my Windows Qt program resumes running after Windows is put to sleep and wakes up, and handle the event appropriately. This looks like half the story with the RegisterPowerSettingNotification function. The other half is how to make this work in Qt.
If my research is correct, it looks like you need a WndProc() override to handle events and the Qt equivalent is QWidget::nativeEvent. If this is correct then the question is how to detect the appropriate event in the nativeEvent override. Can anybody enlighten?
Also, the OP in the linked post used the GUID_SESSION_DISPLAY_STATUS power setting GUID for the RegisterPowerSettingNotification call, which detects when the display turns on/off/dims. Which I'd think is not the same as detecting a sleep event.
An alternative to the RegisterPowerSettingNotification approach could be to use QCoreApplication::installNativeEventFilter as per here. Is this a better way?
Also, it looks like one last alternative is to use the PowerRegisterSuspendResumeNotification function, but I'm not sure how that would link to the callback function; maybe PowerRegisterSuspendResumeNotification is a synchronous function call, or the callback function gets called from the event loop?

I don't understand.  When you make the call to the sleep function, the code should resume execution after the call.  Am I wrong?

@ThomasMatthews it sounds like the OP is interested in detecting when the app resumes running after the OS is put to sleep and woken up. Not when the app code simply calls a sleep function.

@riverofwind have a look at handling the WM_POWERBROADCAST message in your native handler.

@RemyLebeau I am aware of that fellow but how do I handle it? I'm struggling with the technical details. The only code I could find on Google for QWidget::nativeEvent is
MSG* msg = reinterpret_cast<MSG*>(message);
if(msg->message==WM_POWERBROADCAST) Then there's also the issue of getting the proper power setting GUID.

@riverofwind the power setting guids are documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/power-setting-guids But I think RegisterPowerSettingNotification() is the wrong function in your case, try using RegisterSuspendResumeNotification() instead.

@RemyLebeau RegisterSuspendResumeNotification() is asynchronous right and the callback function gets called in the event loop right? Thanks.

@riverofwind the callback function or window is registered, and then called when the event happens, yes. I don't think the callback function is tied to the message loop, but I'm not at a computer right now to test that. But you can register a window instead of a callback and then receive the WM_POWERBROADCAST message

They way I do it in my code is when I receive the WM_POWERBROADCAST function-callback (which presumably is called by some Windows thread which is unrelated to Qt), I implement that callback-function to only send an asynchronous message to the Qt thread (e.g. by calling QApplication::postEvent(), or emitting a signal that goes across a QueuedConnection, or however you want to do it); that way the necessary wake/sleep notification logic can be executed safely inside the Qt thread a very short time later, with no chance of race conditions.

@RemyLebeau If the callback isn't tied to the loop how does it get called? Also for the window message setup don't we need to override nativeEvent? If so I still have the same question as to how to handle the message properly.

@JeremyFriesner Are you saying the callback function is executed in the context of Windows thread outside of the program?

@riverofwind well, it has to be called by something, and since the WC_POWERBROADCAST functionality is part of the Win32 API, which doesn't know anything about Qt, we can be pretty sure that the thread doing the calling isn't any of the Qt threads.

@riverofwind WM_POWERBROADCAST goes through your message loop. I don't know if the callback function is called in a worker thread or the message loop thread. But that is easy to verify by comparing thread IDs using GetCurrentThreadId() inside the callback and message loop. In any case, you already know how to override nativeEvent and get the WM_POWERBROADCAST message from it, you just need a window registration to ensure the message is delivered.

@RemyLebeau Sounds like my code was right then :) I have some homework to do will get back to you guys with the results

Answer:
RegisterPowerSettingNotification cannot detect resume from sleep events.
The code for handling sleep resume events with RegisterSuspendResumeNotification is below for both callback and window message delivery options. The callback option has the callback called from a different thread than the thread initiating the RegisterSuspendResumeNotification function call. Beware of race conditions and use QApplication::postEvent() or a QueuedConnection signal/slot as Jeremy Friesner explained in the comments.
DEVICE_NOTIFY_SUBSCRIBE_PARAMETERS callback = { standbyResume, this }; //the this pointer populates the context parameter, make sure callback doesn't go out of scope
RegisterSuspendResumeNotification(&callback, DEVICE_NOTIFY_CALLBACK);

//OR

RegisterSuspendResumeNotification(HWND(winId()), DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE); //called from a QWidget

static ULONG Replicator::standbyResume(PVOID context, ULONG type, PVOID setting);

ULONG Class::standbyResume(PVOID context, ULONG type, PVOID setting)
{
    if (type == PBT_APMRESUMEAUTOMATIC)
    { //handle event here
        Class* object = reinterpret_cast<Class*>(context); //you can pass objects via pointers in the context parameter
    }
    return 0;
}

bool nativeEvent(const QByteArray& eventType, void* message, long* result);

bool Class::nativeEvent(const QByteArray& eventType, void* message, long* result)
{
    if (eventType == "windows_generic_MSG")
    {
        MSG* msg = reinterpret_cast<MSG*>(message);
        if (msg->message == WM_POWERBROADCAST)
            if (msg->wParam == PBT_APMRESUMEAUTOMATIC)
            { //handle event here
                qDebug() << "suspend resume event";
            }
    }
    return false;
}

